# How can i stop the debugger in a particular variable value?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

how can i set de debugger to stop when some particular variable has a defined value?. For example i have a code that it crash that loops 10000 time to make some postprocessing. I know that the error could be produced from the 7000 iteration up, so i want to stop from there on, avoiding manual loop from the first 7000.
Im using visual studio 2008 and 2010 with c#, i think that the solution will be the same for both.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

What you're looking for is a conditional break point.  Here's how to set it up assuming the variables name is `i`.

- Set a normal breakpoint on the line after the value is set
- Right click on the red dot portion of the breakpoint and select "Condition"
- Enter the condition which you want to check for. Example: `i == 10000`
- Hit OK

Now run your scenario again and the breakpoint will be hit only when the value of `i` equals `10000`.

A word of warning. You can put pretty much any legal C# expression into a conditional break point but it will be evaluated every single time the break point is hit.  That can lead to very slow debugging if use a complex conditional

Comment: Excellent @Jared, that context menu also offers others stop mechanism, never cross my mind doing a right click in the red ball, thanks.

Comment: What if I know only variable value (without variable name)? Is it possible to break code if any of local variables have assigned value which I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Open the breakpoint window and create a new data breakpoint from its menu.

Answer (score -1):

The easy way to do that is:

if (nameVariable = X ) {
BreakPoint: nameVariable; 
}